# import instagram embed.js only in client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using nextjs to render instagram post and lazyload it, so I prefer to import the required script only if it's going the render. But it can't render the post. I can see the embed.js is loaded in network tab however `window.instgrm` is undefined.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const s = document.createElement('script')
  s.async = true
  s.src = `https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js`
  s.onload = () => {
    console.log(window.instgrm) // It's undefined
  }
  const body = document.body
  if (body) {
    body.appendChild(s)
  }
}, [])
```

I tried `http://www.instagram.com/embed.js` and `https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js`, both are not working.

What's wrong with my approach?